# add boostrap select element using button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to create element select with bootstrap class using button onclick. The element inserted into body, but not visible on page.
[image: output]

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />

    <script src="../jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../popper.min.js" ></script><!--https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js-->
    <script src="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function addElement(){
            //normal
            document.body.innerHTML += '<select>'+
                                            '<option>Mustard</option>'+
                                            '<option>Ketchup</option>'+
                                        '</select>';
            //using boostrap class
            document.body.innerHTML+=    '<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">'+
                                            '<option>Mustard</option>'+
                                            '<option>Ketchup</option>'+
                                        '</select>';                    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="addRowBottom" onclick='addElement()'>add row</button>
</body>
```

if put directly on html, it is visible with all styling.

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
      <script src="../jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../popper.min.js" ></script><!--https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js-->
     <script src="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
       <option>Mustard</option>
       <option>Ketchup</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

Comment: The automatic initialization based on the class will only work for elements that are already there when the page loads. If you dynamically add elements later on, you need to properly initialize them yourself via JavaScript - https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Comment: @CBroe, thanks. Yes, we have to initialize in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to create options from an array using parameters passed to the function to determine if that is added to the new `<select>` element.

I took the click off the button and put it in the code where it should be as a best practice.

Some notes and references at appropriate points in the code:

```js
function addElement(newClass, hasMultiple, canSearchLive) {
  const optionValues = ["Mustard", "Ketchup", "Onions"];
  let selectList = document.createElement("select");
  if (hasMultiple) {
    selectList.multiple = "true";
  }
  if (canSearchLive) {
    selectList.dataset.liveSearch = "true";
  }
  selectList.classList.add(newClass);
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option
  optionValues.forEach((element, key) => {
    selectList[key] = new Option(element);
  });
  // need an ID?
  //selectList.id = "hotdogstuff";//append number to make it unique
  document.body.appendChild(selectList);
  // now we turn it live!
  $('select.selectpicker').selectpicker();

}

document.getElementById("addRowBottom")
  .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const useSelectList = true;
    const newClass = useSelectList ? "selectpicker" : "form-control";
    const hasMultiple = false;
    const useLiveSearch = true;
    addElement(newClass, hasMultiple, useLiveSearch);
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" integrity="sha512-ARJR74swou2y0Q2V9k0GbzQ/5vJ2RBSoCWokg4zkfM29Fb3vZEQyv0iWBMW/yvKgyHSR/7D64pFMmU8nYmbRkg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
    referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-yDlE7vpGDP7o2eftkCiPZ+yuUyEcaBwoJoIhdXv71KZWugFqEphIS3PU60lEkFaz8RxaVsMpSvQxMBaKVwA5xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" id="addRowBottom">add row</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As told by @CBroe, we have initialize via javascript to apply bootstrap class function on element when add element dynamically.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
   <script src="../jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../popper.min.js" ></script><!--https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js-->
   <script src="../bootstrap-4.6.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function addElement(){
        //normal
        document.body.innerHTML += '<select>'+
                                        '<option>Mustard</option>'+
                                        '<option>Ketchup</option>'+
                                    '</select>';
        //using boostrap class
        document.body.innerHTML+=    '<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">'+
                                        '<option>Mustard</option>'+
                                        '<option>Ketchup</option>'+
                                    '</select>';
         $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();                    
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button type="button" id="addRowBottom" onclick='addElement()'>add row</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please not the security risk for `innerHTML` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML  use proper care.